# Python ForLoop with nested after() functions happening after loop

Tags: python, for-loop, time, tkinter

I am trying to create a function that will repeat a block of code three times.
The code has a for loop to alter the background at 500ms intervals. I want this to be repeated three times.

```
for x in range(0,3):
    window.after(500, lambda: window.configure(bg = "blue"))
    window.after(1000, lambda: window.configure(bg = "green"))
    window.after(1500, lambda: window.configure(bg = "yellow"))
    window.after(2000, lambda: window.configure(bg = "purple"))
    window.after(2500, lambda: window.configure(bg = "red"))
    window.after(3000, lambda: window.configure(bg = "#a1dbcd"))
    print x
```

In the IDE 'x' is printed out three times but the window background only cycles once.

Can someone please help me either fix this code or find an alternate way to do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fernando Matsumoto has answered your question, but here's a slightly more compact way to do it.

```
import Tkinter as tk

bgcolors = ("blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "red", "#a1dbcd")

def cycle():
    delta = 500
    delay = delta
    for x in range(3):
        for c in bgcolors:
            window.after(delay, lambda c=c: window.configure(bg=c))
            delay += delta
        print x

window = tk.Tk()
window.pack_propagate(0)

b = tk.Button(window, text='cycle bg', command=cycle)
b.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much; I like iterating the colours and incrementing the delay. This should work perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

You are calling

```
window.after(500, lambda: window.configure(bg = "blue"))
window.after(1000, lambda: window.configure(bg = "green"))
...
```

3 times. This is equivalent to writing:

```
window.after(500, lambda: window.configure(bg = "blue"))
window.after(500, lambda: window.configure(bg = "blue"))
window.after(500, lambda: window.configure(bg = "blue"))
```

After 500ms, you set the background to blue 3 times.

To do set the background in a row, add an interval every iteration. For instance, instead of

```
for i in range(3):
    window.after(500, lambda: window.configure(bg = "blue"))
    window.after(1000, lambda: window.configure(bg = "green"))
```

do

```
for i in range(3):
    window.after(i * 1000 + 500, lambda: window.configure(bg = "blue"))
    window.after(i * 1000 + 1000, lambda: window.configure(bg = "green"))
```

This code will do:

- First iteration:

  ```
  window.after(500, lambda: window.configure(bg = "blue"))
  window.after(1000, lambda: window.configure(bg = "green"))
  ```
- Second iteration:

  ```
  window.after(1500, lambda: window.configure(bg = "blue"))
  window.after(2000, lambda: window.configure(bg = "green"))
  ```
- Third iteration:

  ```
  window.after(2500, lambda: window.configure(bg = "blue"))
  window.after(3000, lambda: window.configure(bg = "green"))
  ```

Notice how the intervals are increasing on every iteration instead of staying the same.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's easy to see the logic behind it all. PM 2Ring's answer is a little bit more compact. Cheers :)