# Tkinter wait function is not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make an animation using Tkinter Text Widget. I want it to write each frame on the Text widget every 1 second. Here is my current code:

```
from tkinter import *

frames = ["-o","--o","---o"]

speed = 1000
def clear():
    text.delete(0.0, END)

def movie(event):
    text.delete(0.0, END)
    for frame in range(len(frames)):
        text.insert(END, frames[frame])
        root.after(speed, clear)

root = Tk()
root.title("Animation")
root.minsize(400,400)
root.maxsize(width=root.winfo_screenwidth()-20, height=root.winfo_screenheight()-20)
text = Text(root, highlightcolor="black", highlightbackground="white",width=400, insertbackground="white", height=400, foreground="white", background="black", font="Courier")
text.pack()
root.bind("<Return>", movie)
```

But, the output of this code is

```
-o--o---o
```

instead of:

```
-o[wait a second][clear]--o[wait a second][clear]---o[wait a second][clear]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You aren't using the `.after` method correctly. My code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34313194/4014959) may be helpful. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32766256/4014959

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem! The .after() function almost works like the return function. In that, when called the current function is stopped. This is my fixed code:

```
from tkinter import *
frame = 0
frames = ["-o","--o","---o"]

speed = 1000
def clear():
    text.delete(0.0, END)

def movie(event=""):
    global frame
    if frame < len(frames):
        text.delete(0.0, END)
        text.insert(END,frames[frame])
        frame += 1
        root.after(speed, movie)

def movie1(event):
    global frame
    frame = 0
    movie("<Return>")

root = Tk()
root.title("Animation")
root.minsize(400,400)
root.maxsize(width=root.winfo_screenwidth()-20, height=root.winfo_screenheight()-20)
text = Text(root, highlightcolor="black", highlightbackground="white",width=400, insertbackground="white", height=400, foreground="white", background="black", font="Courier")
text.pack()
root.bind("<Return>", movie)
```

Comment: Nope, that's not how `after()` works :-) It doesn't block or "return". `after()` schedules a function to run after some amount of time, which may *appear* to behave like you describe in some conditions, but it's obviously not the same! (if you ever did JavaScript, think `setTimeout()`. Also see [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method)).

Comment: But, then how was my oringinal problem wrong? Please make another answer.